# jQuery check if at least two text inputs are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my form :

```
<FORM id="form1">                          
            Fields :
                        <fieldset name="titles">
                        <br>
            <INPUT class = "fit" type="text" name="title">
                        <br>
            <INPUT class = "fit" type="text" name="title">
                        <br>
                        <INPUT class = "fit" type="text" name="title">
                        <br>
                        <INPUT class = "fit" type="text" name="title">                     
                        </fieldset>
            </FORM>
```

How can I check if at least two out of these four fields are filled? Here's what i'I've tried :

```
$('#form1').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        title: {
          required: "input[name='title']",
          minlength: 2
      },
      messages: {
            title: "You must fill at least two titles!"
        }
    }
});
```

But it's not working, it always returns a valid form... I'm a newbie to jQuery, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which plugin are you using, do you definitely have the validate plugin included on the page? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: The `name` attribute has to be unique or followed by square brackets to allow multiple values.

Comment: @IanJamieson the plugin is included, and i don't see any errors in the console...

Comment: Which plugin is it so I can check the documentation?

Comment: I have "http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js" AND
"http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"

Answer (score 2):

For 1 statement to grab both 'select' and 'input' elements, simply change your single jQuery selector  to a multiple selector, 
Eg:-

```
$(this).find('input[type=text], select').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != "") valid+=1;
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this with the button:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(){
        if($('input[text]').length < 2) {
                alert('at least two text inputs are filled');
               return false;
            }
      });
```